# Combined file_get_contents and base tag

Tags: php, file-get-contents, base-tag

Here I have code for showing an external page within my page (similar to iframe but I grab the source):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;    

echo $data;
?>
```

When I call the script, all is OK - but I can't close javascript window and can't see the content... the close link doesn't work. What is the problem? How to solve this?

UPDATE: or is there any function (JS or jquery) which will hide 'DIV' on right click on him. THANKS

Comment: what javascript can you show that code?

Comment: i really don't now. In head section is some links to script files and i don't know does base tag work only for links in body section or in body and head...

Comment: Please see the www.pluspon.com/get.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course using `str_replace()` to make them invisible.

Use this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){parent.close_home_banner()});</script></head>'.$data;

$data = str_replace('<div id="active_banner_wrap">', '<div id="active_banner_wrap" style="display:none;"> ' , $data); 
$data = str_replace('<div id="home_banner_campaign_wrapper">', '<div id="home_banner_campaign_wrapper" style="display:none;"> ' , $data); 

echo $data;

?>
```

To avoid javascripts:

```
$data =  str_replace('<script>', '<removed>' , $data);
$data =   str_replace('</script>', '</removed>' , $data);
```

Comment: Yes it's usefull for this web site but it's not working when I change URL address:(

Comment: I need some universal solution to work all elements on page whatever is URL.

Comment: You want to remove all scripts ?

Comment: No I need to work javascript to can close this window on my page.

Comment: Then you will use click function of that banner. Wait

Comment: Maybe some function to desable javascript. Is there some similar function?

Comment: you can remove script tags, you cant disable javascript on browser.

Comment: codepad.viper-7.com/jEkux2 is not solution becouse If I change url exapmle groupon this code will not work

Comment: example, first all is rendering then when I click on right click close div which I selected

Comment: I'm Update my question: is there any function (JS or jquery) which will hide 'DIV' on right click on him. THANKS